# WebRTC/Kurento One way, one-to-many broadcasting with server-side recording

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, rtsp, kurento

So I'm looking into Kurento to see if I can use it for what I need.

What I want is to have a mobile app that records and sends video to server in real-time (or as close to it as possible), and the server to store the video in its file system as it receives it. At the same time, a browser web application (or several instances) should be able to display the video that is being recorded as "real-time" as possible, and be able to view it whenever it wants, so the mobile app needs to send to the server and the server needs to store the video regardless of what the browser web app does.

Seeing the tutorials, what seems closer is the "Advanced One to one video call" example. But it needs the second client to accept the connection and also sends video from the second client, while I just want to view the mobile app video in the browser.

Can it be done with Kurento?

Suggestions for other SDKs or solutions not involving Kurento are also welcome

Thanks

EDIT: changed the title for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with kurento. You just need to get the [kurento-one-2-many](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-one2many-call) tutorial, and add recording in the presenter side. Easy!

Comment: Thanks! do you know if I can use kurento to convert the WebRTC stream to RTSP?

Comment: @mikepa88 you can publish that stream in RTP or SRTP. Would that be enough?

Comment: @igarcia I need to have both the WebRTC for broadcasting to Kurento client apps and an RTSP stream for a third party app, so I guess the KMS would have to re-stream in RTSP

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with [flashphoner](https://flashphoner.com)
It supports real-time recording of WebRTC streams with re-broadcasting.

1. Publish a stream to server.

   ```
   var stream = session.createStream({name:"mystream",record:true});
   stream.publish();
   ```
2. Play stream from server

   ```
   var stream = session.createStream({name:"mystream"});
   stream.play();
   ```
3. Stop stream. Recording complete.

   ```
   stream.unpublish();
   ```

It works for Android and for iOS. As a result your stream will be recorded in mp4.